# ORDER by multiple queries in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, case, inner-join

I am trying to build a chat list page where latest sent/received contact is shown at the top from one table. For this, I have a table `smshistory` where i store sent/received sms with numbers where one is company phone and other is client phone number

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `smshistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromnumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tonumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sms` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `smshistory`
--

INSERT INTO `smshistory` (`id`, `fromnumber`, `tonumber`, `sms`, `added`) VALUES
(1, 'companynum', 'client1num', 'Hello', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(2, 'companynum', 'client2num', 'Hello', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(3, 'companynum', 'client3num', 'Hello', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(4, 'client1num', 'companynum', 'Hi', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(5, 'companynum', 'client1num', 'Hello', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(6, 'client1num', 'companynum', 'Hi', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(7, 'client2num', 'companynum', 'Hi', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(8, 'companynum', 'client2num', 'Hello', '2021-07-16 12:28:23'),
(9, 'client3num', 'companynum', 'Hi', '2021-07-16 12:28:23');
```

As first message will always be from company number, so I am showing `DISTINCT` list with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`tonumber`) FROM `smshistory` WHERE `fromnumber` = $companynum
```

Which gives me list like:

```
client1num
client2num
client3num
```

**Requirement:**

What I require is to show the `DISTINCT` with order of `added DESC` column in a way that if a client's number is in `fromnumber` or `tonumber`, it should show at top. So, according to my table, results should be:

```
client3num
client2num
client1num
```

Fiddle is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4256d1d/1

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Just to observe: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: I don't understand the rule for the sorting. If it's because the rows have the numerals '3', '2',' and '1' in them then the db desgn is perhaps in need of a rapid rethink!

Comment: @JSBach Yes, DB design is very bad but since its my assignment, so i can't change it and need to provide results accordingly.

Comment: So the question is 'how do I sort a collection of strings according to the numerals contained within those strings?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the rows that contain `$companynum` either in `fromnumber` or in `tonumber` you must extract the client's number with a `CASE` expression and use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates.
Finally, sort the results by the max value of `added`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN fromnumber = $companynum THEN tonumber ELSE fromnumber END client_num
FROM smshistory
WHERE $companynum IN (fromnumber, tonumber)
GROUP BY client_num
ORDER BY MAX(added) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It solved. Just another question, if there is another field like message which store the sms body sent and received, how would we show the last message sent or received to show on chat heads?

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question you can use the following query:

```
SELECT distinct client_num from ( 
SELECT CASE WHEN fromnumber = 'companynum' THEN tonumber 
ELSE fromnumber END client_num 
FROM smshistory ORDER BY id DESC ) as a
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please check my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35fad3/13. According to that fiddle, answer should be client2num, client1num, client3num. My question was not to always sort it like client3num, client2num, client1num but who even has latest entry in either tonumber or fromnumber column.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question 'How do I sort a de-normalised collection of strings (that a follow a very constrained pattern) according to the numerals contained within those strings?', here's one method...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;

CREATE TABLE x
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
,bad_string VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO x VALUES (11,'client2num'),(17,'client3num'),(21,'client1num');

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(bad_string,'client',''),'num','') p FROM x;
+---+
| p |
+---+
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
+---+
```

...which can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(bad_string,'client',''),'num','') DESC;
+----+------------+
| id | bad_string |
+----+------------+
| 17 | client3num |
| 11 | client2num |
| 21 | client1num |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but you got it wrong, its not about sorting out according to numerical. Its that we have 2 values and 2 columns where one value be will same but other value can change. Both values can be in either of 2 columns in a record and there can be multiple records of a same changing value. We got to get distinct list of changing values with order that we can get the changing value at top which is in the latest record regardless of the column.

Comment: Well, in previous comments, you very much indicated that this *was* the case, so I'm just going to leave this one for others.